# code hangs when drawing grid canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, grid

I am trying to draw a grid in a canvas. The grid has a spacing of 10, and each grid point has a size of 1. But when i run this code my browser hangs for ages, and the grid looks like a solid box. I checked for infinite for loops but as far as i saw there are none. So i don't know what is going wrong here. The snipped doesn't have the hanging problem, but also draws an ugly box instead of a nice grid.

al suggestions are welcome!

if something isn't clear let me know so i can explain.

```js
var canvas;
var grid_spacing = 100;
var points = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
 canvas = document.getElementById('index-canvas');
 setup_grid();
 for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  points[i].draw();
 }
});



function setup_grid(){
 if (canvas.getContext) {
  var canvas_context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  for (var x = grid_spacing; x < window.innerWidth-grid_spacing; x+=grid_spacing) {
   for (var y = grid_spacing; y < window.innerHeight-grid_spacing; y+=grid_spacing) {
    points.push(new Plus_icon(x,y, canvas_context));
   }
  }
 }
}


class Plus_icon{
 
 constructor(x,y,c){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.c = c;
 }

 draw(){
  this.c.ellipse(this.x, this.y, 5, 5, Math.PI, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  this.c.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  this.c.fill();
 }
}
```

```css
#index-canvas{
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="index-content">
  <canvas id="index-canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: the same problem is still there if i change spacing to 100 and size to 5

Comment: Add `this.c.beginPath()` to the first line of the draw function. Without it you keep adding ellipses to the path, after 1st you draw the 2nd and the 1st and 2nd is filled, after 3 it fill the 1st, 2nd, 3rd . `beginPath` removes the old path.